# Can't remove a trailing line break in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Python 3 in Windows 10.

The paths are displayed correctly in file.txt (no `\n` at the end of each line) but on standout there is a `\n` appended to each line leading to error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\Users\Username\\Downloads\\desktop.ini\n'  #this happens to any file whatever the extension .ini, .txt, and so on.
```

The code is:

```
# ... code above here ...

path_list = [] # code to collect and append each path to paths

paths = '\n'.join(path_list).strip("\\n") #stripping "\\n" or "\n" produces same result regardless

with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for item in paths:
        file.write(str(item))
```

Comment: You are escaping the first backslash. So you are stripping the literal ``\`` followed by an `n`... This is the default behavior of `strip` so just do `'\n'.join(path_list).strip()`...

Comment: use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for the task. Also, instead of `strip('\n')` try `replace('\\n', '')`

Comment: But why do you even need `paths`? Why not just `for path in path_list: file.write(path)`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo for some reason,\n still gets returned as the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback. It is not clear from where this error is coming from. Have a look at how to provide a [mre]

Comment: Please don't edit solutions inside the question. You are free to post an answer to your own question, but the question itself is not the place for answers...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I sense the wording of the "Answer your question" button is confusing in a way that it may lead a newbie to think that the button is reserved to answer his own question only. I will know for next time. Thanks.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not sure what's confusing about that. It's exactly what it is. A button to *Answer your question*...

Comment: @Tomerikoo. Answering my question does not exclude answering with my own answer. Just a misinterpretation.

Comment: I don't follow... Anyway you can still do that, and even accept that answer if it actually solved your problem

Comment: @Tomerikoo. In my mind, I could not answer my own question if I did not have my own answer.

Comment: Oh I think I understand your confusion now. Anyway it's fine. As long as you solved your problem and there is no existing answer, you can add one yourself. By the way, the way you did it is perfectly fine. It is a common thing where comments actually answer the question and the OP posts it as an answer with attribution to the commenter, just as you did. Happy to help and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You construct one single string as `paths`:

> ```
> path_list = [] # code to collect and append each path to paths
>
> paths = '\n'.join(path_list).strip("\\n") # strips literal \ + n not newline \n
> ```

then you write the path character wise into your file:

> ```
> with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file:
>     for item in paths:
>         file.write(str(item))
> ```

You can simplify this to:

```
path_list = [ "c:/temp/file1.txt",  "c:/temp/file1.txt\n" ] 
paths = '\n'.join(part.strip() for part in path_list) # strip whitespaces from paths 
with open("file.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(paths)
```

The error message you show only makes sense if you read the file back in and process it linewise to do something with the file. When you read the file back in to process it you need to clean the line:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # strip the newline at its end
        # do something with line
```

Comment: My mistake...in path_list, I have several paths included already. This was confusing as I stated it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Tomerikoo in the comments helped me solve my issue:

> But why do you even need `paths`? Why not just:
>
> ```
> for path in path_list: 
>     file.write(path)
> ```